# Convert the for loop to accept ID type

Tags: objective-c

I want to be able to reuse this method so it's not restricted by the class being called in the for loop declaration.

The problem is the compiler has no idea what id actually is, so I cannot use . notation on it. I need to cast it to a whatever type of event class i'll be passing it, instead of having to repeat the method for `SpecialEvent1` `SpecialEvent2` `SpecialEvent3`

So instead of `for (SpecialEvent1 *event in day)` I want to be able to do something like `for (id event in day)` but problem occurs when I try to access the time or duration property

```
- (NSArray *)sumDay:(NSArray *)day {
    NSInteger morning = 0, afternoon = 0, evening = 0, night = 0;

    for (SpecialEvent1 *event in day) {
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:event.time];
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:date];
        NSInteger hour = [components hour];

        if (hour < 12) {
            morning += event.duration;
        }
        else if (hour < 18) {
            afternoon += event.duration;
        }
        else if (hour < 20) {
            evening += event.duration;
        }
        else {
            night += event.duration;
        }
    }

    NSArray *sums = @[@(morning), @(afternoon), @(evening), @(night)];
    return sums; 
}
```

Comment: you haven't asked a question or really explained a problem. do you mean you want to use the loop with any object which has a `time` variable ?

Comment: You may want to use a protocol (which will respond to "time"), or use a class `Event`, and `SpecialEvent1`, `SpecialEvent2`, `SpecialEvent3` class will inherit from.

Comment: @Wain yes, any object i will pass will have the time and duration property on it

Comment: @Larme my ```SpecialEvent1```, ```SpecialEvent2```, ```SpecialEvent3``` classes are subclass of the ```Event``` class. But the problem is time and duration property only belong to the subclasses so called the Event superclass won't work as that doesn't hold the property i'm trying to access

Comment: In this example, `Event` has a `time` and `duration` property, so why don't its subclasses?

Comment: sorry I was editing the question before posting it and didn't realise that typo. i've amended the question. Currently my Event class doesn't have time and duration, but the subclasses i've created from it SpecialEvent1 does include time and duration property

Comment: if the subclasses all have the properties why don't you move them to the superclass ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you aren't interested in objects that don't have a `time` or `duration` property, you could define a protocol which says this:

```
@protocol TimedEvent <NSObject>
-(NSTimeInterval)time;
-(NSTimeInterval)duration;
@end
```

Then go through the array like this:

```
- (NSArray *)sumDay:(NSArray *)day {
    NSInteger morning = 0, afternoon = 0, evening = 0, night = 0;

    for (id<TimedEvent> event in day) {
        if (![event conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TimedEvent)]) {
            continue;
        }
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:event.time];
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:date];
        NSInteger hour = [components hour];

        if (hour < 12) {
            morning += event.duration;
        }
        else if (hour < 18) {
            afternoon += event.duration;
        }
        else if (hour < 20) {
            evening += event.duration;
        }
        else {
            night += event.duration;
        }
    }

    NSArray *sums = @[@(morning), @(afternoon), @(evening), @(night)];
    return sums; 
}
```